# How do I convert a pre-1970 date to epoch in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, epoch

How do I convert a pre-1970 date to epoch in Python 3.x?

Many examples are given for the oposite direction, where one has a negative epoch value and gets the date by using timedelta. However I cannot find examples where we have the real date time and want to get epoch time stamp.

For example i am doing the following:

```
timestamp = datetime.datetime(1964, 12, 1, 0, 0).timestamp()
```

Which gives me "OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument"

(The reason I want to do this is to edit the creation date on scanned pictures so that it reflects the time of exposure, in stead of the date of scanning.)

My exact setup:
Windows x64
Python 3.7

Comment: I just ran that exact line on Python 3.8.2 (built for Alpine Linux if that matters, though running under WSL on Windows), and it ran fine, producing `-160444800.0`. You're going to need to be more specific about your setup to aid reproducers.

Comment: I can reproduce the error on Windows 10.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thanks for testing! 
I am using 3.7.9 on windows so it may indeed be fixed. 
Ill try and install 3.8 right away. 

Edit: Your next answer crossed mine. Well, a windows bug then. That is harder to do something about. Maybe someone has figured out a workaround?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this is an as yet unfixed bug on Windows: [Issue 37527: Timestamp conversion on windows fails with timestamps close to EPOCH](https://bugs.python.org/issue37527)